# R writing a function to extract data from an Oracle database

Tags: r, oracle, rodbc

I'm trying to write a function in R, which takes an input and adds it to a pre-defined SQL query. This is to avoid rewriting the same query every time the input changes, and using the function instead.

But I am having problems with the syntax of the function.

**The Function**

The function takes as `input` a unique ID, and returns a site name(s).

```
library(RODBC)

con= odbcConnect(dsn = "DB", uid="morp101", pwd="abcdxyz1234",rows_at_time=500)

getsitename=function(input) {

sitename=sqlQuery(con,"Select DISTINCT(SITE_NAME) FROM SITE_TABLE 
                    WHERE SITE_CODE = '&input&'")
return(sitename)

}
```

The above function should give the following output when tested

```
getsitename(1011APQ)
```

> Result: Madison Bay

However the syntax is wrong, not sure how to concatenate the `input` correctly.

Any advice would be highly appreciated. And apologies for lack of reproducible data, was not sure how I could obtain it for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `paste0()` to create your query:

```
getsitename=function(input) {
  query = paste0("Select DISTINCT(SITE_NAME) FROM SITE_TABLE WHERE SITE_CODE = '", input, "'")
  sitename=sqlQuery(con,query)
  return(sitename)
}
```

So when `input='1234'`, the `paste0()` statement returns

```
"Select DISTINCT(SITE_NAME) FROM SITE_TABLE WHERE SITE_CODE = '1234'"
```

Comment: When I wrap the paste0() into a function, I get the following error message: Error in names(frame)[names(frame) == "x"] <- name : 
  names() applied to a non-vector. Here is the function sitename=function(input) {
  site=sqlQuery(con,paste0("Select DISTINCT(SITE_NAME) FROM SITE_TABLE WHERE SITE_CODE = '",input, "'"))
  return(site)
}

Comment: Got any variable or function named `names` in your environment? See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39611953/r-error-names-applied-to-a-non-vector).

Comment: I closed the tab in the RStudio IDE corresponding to the function, and it worked. Strange! Thanks for your help